# Graph Theory, Cograph

Tags: graph-theory

A graph which is P$_4$-free (path on 4 vertices and with 3 edges) is called a cograph. A graph is called complement reducible if it can be reduced to an edgeless graph by successively taking complements within components.

Prove that a graph G is a cograph if and only if it is complement reducible. Use the first part of this problem and Lovasz’ Perfect Graph Theorem to prove that every cograph is perfect. (Weak Perfect Graph Theorem, Lovasz ’72). A graph is perfect if and only if its complement is perfect.

I'm trying to visualize/draw this first and I'm not sure I'm getting it right. Help please!

Comment: I'm not sure I get the definition.  Take $C_5$, the cycle of length 5.  Its complement is $C_5$, so you can't get rid of any edge by taking complements.  But $C_5$ is not $P_4$-free.

Comment: @manuel but that's consistent with what they're trying to show.  Namely, $C_5$ is NOT $P_4$ free, therefore it is not complement reducible.

Comment: Hah !  Sorry I totally misunderstood the definition.

Comment: Are you allowed to use known properties of cographs ?  In particular, "A cograph is a graph in which every connected induced subgraph has a disconnected complement" (seen here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cograph) is extremely useful.  Otherwise, you can prove it yourself - it's feasible by induction.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that if a graph doesn't have $P_4$ as a subgraph, then you can never have any paths of length $3$; at most two edges can be end-to-end.

Here's an example of the sequence of moves I believe they're describing. The star graphs $S_n$ are all $P_4$-free but can get moderately large, and make a good example to see what's happening.

[image]

Here we start with $S_5$ and take the complement. This leaves us with two connected components: One edgeless graph with $1$ nodes, $E_1$, and a complete graph with $4$ nodes. When we take the complement of each component, all edges are gone.

Unfortunately these sketches are about all I've got, as I'm not terribly familiar with these terms or theorems!